# Merge/Combine continuous date records using loop in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, gaps-and-islands

I have a requirement where I need to merge records which are continuous and belong to a certain type of group and few other conditions.

1. List item

To combine records  -we should consider it as continuous only if it start as **Main group**, so the 1st records in here should be treated as individual even thought it is continuous

2. List item

Do not Combine if it does not end as Main group,

3. List item

If there is gap of a day then don't combine

```
MemberName   Group  StartDate      EndDAte
Priya         Sub   01/01/2017     01/20/2017 --Do not merge,not started in Main
Priya         Main  01/20/2017     01/30/2017 --merge
Priya         Sub   01/30/2017     02/05/2017 --merge
Priya         Main  02/06/2017     02/06/2017 --Do not merge,Break
Priya         sub   02/07/2017     02/15/2017 --Do not merge,not started in Main
Priya         Main  02/15/2017     02/20/2017 --Merge
Priya         Main  02/20/2017     02/25/2017 --Do not merge,Break
Priya         sub   02/28/2017     02/28/2017 --Do not merge,break also did not end as Main
```

output should look like:

```
MemberName   Group  StartDate      EndDAte
Priya        Sub    01/01/2017     01/20/2017 
Priya        Main   01/20/2017     02/05/2017
Priya        Main   02/06/2017     02/06/2017
Priya        sub    02/07/2017     02/15/2017
Priya        Main   02/15/2017     02/25/2017
Priya        sub    02/28/2017     02/28/2017
```

I have to use a If-while loop here.

Comment: So what's your problem? What have you done so far? With while loop it should be quite simple to do this. You can also use window functions but that's going to be a lot more complex.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean by "Do not Combine if it does not end as Main group", but could you clarify with additional examples for this criteria?.

Comment: @james Z, i used temp tables and derived the output but it felt huge and inefficient ,i wanted to use loops but iam new to loops concept in sQL,can you please help me write loop for it

Comment: @SqlZim i meant if there is a gap in the end i meant we should not join it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't done using loops, but wanted to test how this could be done using window functions. The result is quite ugly. Most likely it could be done easier too, but you might pick up some tricks if you begin to investigate how this works from inside out:

```
select * 
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by MemberName, GapTotal, MainGrp order by StartDate) as RN,
    first_value(EndDate) over (partition by MemberName, GapTotal, MainGrp order by StartDate desc) as LastEndDate
    from (
       select * , sum(Main) over (partition by MemberName order by StartDate) as MainGrp
       from (
            select *, case when [Group] = 'Main' and row_number() over (partition by MemberName, GapTotal, [Group] order by StartDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as Main
            from (
                select *, sum(Gap) over (partition by MemberName order by StartDate) as GapTotal
                from (
                    select 
                      *, 
                      isnull(datediff(day, lag(EndDate) over (order by StartDate), StartDate),0) as Gap 
                    from #tmp
                ) V
            ) W
        ) X
    ) Y
) Z
where RN = 1
order by MemberName, StartDate
```

This uses mostly trick with running total, creating groupings with it that are then used to determine if rows can be merged or not.

[Example](http://rextester.com/WFPCW50316)

Comment: Hi James ,thanks for the help , but requirement changed to loof for gap for  7 days, i,e if members has different start and end dates and date diff between them is <=7 then combine that records.how would i make it dynamic on gap ?

Comment: No upvotes and not marked as answer, and then you ask almost month later how to change it to your new requirements?

Comment: But anyhow, this handles the gap, so change it according to your needs `datediff(day, lag(EndDate) over (order by StartDate), StartDate)`

Comment: Hi james, iam new to stack overfolw so i dnt know the concept of voting,but i am so grateful for ur answer and i will mark it now.

Comment: If you add a case making the gap 0 when it's smaller than your requirement, then it should work, I mean this part: `datediff(day, lag(EndDate) over (order by StartDate), StartDate)`

Comment: Awesome Thanks James it worked,i was trying to handle in above loops and got struked